# v-select multiple not setting value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a **v-select** implemented on my site now, i have a scenario in which i have to set array of data into the select using the **global event on** let me show the code first

**HTML**

```
<v-select
              multiple
              :searchable="false"
              label="phone"
              :disabled="appointment.phone_in_notes"
              :no-drop="true"
              :options="customerPhones"
              :value="customerPhones"
            ></v-select>
```

**vuejs**

```
mounted() {
    const vm = this;
      this.$eventHub.$on("on-create-appointment-click-open-add-appointment-with-user", (customer) => {
          this.showModal= true;
          this.appointment.purchase_order=customer.purchase_order;
          // this.customerLocation=customer.locations[0].address1;
          this.customer.fname=customer.first_name;
          this.customer.lname=customer.last_name;
          this.customerPhones=[92233,123];
          // this.location.phones=[92233,123];
          // this.appointment.phone_id=['92233'];
          // this.appointment.phone_in_notes=['92233'];
          // console.log(customer.cid);
          // console.log(customer.locations[0].address1);
          this.customer_test_valiues=customer;
      });
    this.$eventHub.$on("show-appointment-modal", data => {
      Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.apply(this), {
        showModal: true
      });
      this.fetchServiceTypes();
      this.fetchEmployees();
      if (data) {
        this.fromEvent = data;
        this.setScheduleOnCalendarClick(data);
        this.getEmployeesForSchedule(data);
      }
    });
  },
```

the data is being set to simple inputs normally but when i try to set array to the **v-select** it doesnot work i have tried a number of combinations but none seem to be working for me any help?

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing its a reactivity issue.
try `this.$set(this.customer, 'fname', customer.first_name)`
checkout their docs on [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Vuetify v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api), you need to use `:items` instead of `:options`

```
   <v-select
      multiple
      :searchable="false"
      label="phone"
      :disabled="appointment.phone_in_notes"
      :no-drop="true"
      :items="customerPhones"
      :value="customerPhones"
    ></v-select>
```